# PHP include statement echoes '?'

Tags: php

I have two PHP files running on my web server,

a.php:

```
<?php
    echo 'A';
    include('b.php');
    echo 'B';
?>
```

b.php:

```
<?php
function foo(){
    return 0;
}
```

Upon sending a POST request to `a.php` from C#'s `HttpWebRequest`, the response I got is:

```
A?B
```

However, after removing

```
include('b.php');
```

The response I get is without the `?` character printed:

```
AB
```

Why is the `?` even there? How should I get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: I think the c# tag is a bit misplaced here

Comment: @BSoD_ZA Yep it seems so! Sorry, I'm quite poor at tags ><

Comment: Why does the title say you're getting a `$` but the question say you're getting `?`?

Comment: woops, seems like i forgot to edit the title!

Comment: Do you have any chars before <?php on b.php?

Comment: Is this the exact code?

Comment: Yes, this is the exact code. I copied both files verbatim onto here. I'm using WAMP btw.

Comment: May there be a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) on the file?

Comment: @deceze I've analyzed both files with a hex editor and there seems to be nothing extra on the file

Answer (score 0):

After reanalyzing both a.php and b.php (as deceze suggested) more carefully again this time, it turns out that both files did indeed contain the byte-order-mark,

```
0xEF-0xBB-0xBF
```

in the front.

The BOMs did not reflect in Notepad, and it turns out they were there because the files were UTF-8 encoded.

To solve this, I simply opened up the files in Notepad, and saved them using ANSI encoding. The BOMs disappeared, and the '?' no longer showed.